# The Account's RollUp Summary field wasn't populating properly since there is a filter criteria

Tags: roll-up-summary

The Account's RollUp Summary field wasn't populating properly since there is a filter criteria , i have seen records are populating until/unless if it's satisfies the criteria , But few records not populates even filter criteria matches

Comment: Welcome to SFSE.  Please take a moment to read [ask] and take the [tour]. Please [edit] your post to include the rollup field criteria and an example of where it doesn't work.  Use screenshots if needed.